# TCL string prepend

Tags: string, tcl, prepend

Just a simple but very often needed operation - how to prepend a string to a variable:

```
set s "world!!!"
prepend s "Hello " #how to accomplish this effectively?
puts $s
#should print "Hello world!!!"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a procedure `prepend`:

```
proc prepend {s_var txt} {
  upvar 1 $s_var s
  set s "${txt}${s}"
}
```

That does exactly what you want. But I think usually it's simpler to write:

```
set s "Hello ${s}"
```

Comment: {set s "Hello $s"} is this the most effective way in TCL?

Comment: Nice answer. You have it in your proc but probably worth also wrapping curlies around the s in the second example too. set s "Hello ${s}"

Comment: @Brian: I added the curly braces although for *this* use it does not make a difference.

Comment: @Narek: At least I am not aware of a more efficient way. But anyhow: It's much slower than e.g. `append`.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I've used TCL, but have you tried this:

```
set s "world!"
set s "hello $s"
puts $s
```

Comment: The same question: {set s "Hello $s"} is this the most effective way in TCL?

Comment: What do you mean by effective?

Comment: I mean the fastest way available in TCL for this operation.

Comment: @Narek, you you need to assemble a long string from chunks which need to be prepended, and you do not know how many chunks will be there, it's better to keep a list of these chunks (you can `lappend` chunks to it) and then when the list is ready assemble one string using `append` by getting chunks from the list in the order you need.

Comment: @Narek: If you want to know what the most effective technique is, and by that you mean what is the fastest way (not the only definition of “effective” of course) then learn to use the [`time`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/time.htm) command.